# Parameter order for unittest.TestCase.assertEqual

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

Is it `assertEqual(actual, expected)` or `assertEqual(expected, actual)`?

On the one hand I'm seeing lots of code using `assertEqual(actual, expected)`. This includes [examples in the unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) and [examples in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests).

However, this test `assertEqual('foo', 'bar')` is giving me the output

```
- foo
+ bar
```

Which happens to be the same as for a PHPUnit test with `assertEquals( 'foo', 'bar' );`

```
-'foo'
+'bar'
```

And PHPUnit has `$expected` as first parameter, followed by `$actual`. This diff is also what I'd expect for `expected, actual`.

So is all this Python code I'm seeing doing it wrong?

I checked the definition of the unittest method, though that has the extremely helpful `first, second` parameter names.

Comment: I can't but agree the `assertEqual` in `unittest` is pretty confusing / ambiguous. As you write, "extremely helpful" parameter names don't help much. BTW It's a pity there seems to be no general consensus on the parameters' order - even JUnit and TestNG both use different order...

Answer (score 8):

I typically use `assertEqual(expected, actual)` because the output message makes more sense.

Code:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestClass(TestCase):
    def test_equal(self):
        expected = 1
        actual = 2
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

Output:

```
2 != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :2
```

If order is reversed, then the message will incorrectly say:

```
Expected :2
Actual   :1
```

Comment: In the current version of Python's unittest, the output is quite different, i.e. there are no `Expected` or `Actual` labels output. So following the examples from the docs (i.e. `self.assertEqual(actual, expected)`) does make more sense now?

Answer (score 6):

As per the [`assertEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) document:

> Test that **first and second are equal**. If the values do not compare equal, the test will fail.

So, you may put expected and actual at any place and it will return the same result. But it is the common practice to use *actual* result as the first argument and *expected* result as the second argument.  It is also demonstrated in [Python 3's Unittest Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

```
s = 'hello world'
self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the failure message for assertions like `assertGreaterEqual(a, b)` indicates the order in Python unitest for these kind of assertions is (`actual, expected`), because it expects that a >= b, in other words, that the actual value is greater than or equal to the expected value.  Your assertion failure messages will be confusing unless you adopt the correct order.

PHPUnit and other jUnit-based testing frameworks on the other hand typically use (`expected, actual`)